# Joining three tables using linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework, code-first

I have three tables as:

```
 public class Description
    {
        public int DescriptionID { get; set; }

        // Attributes 

        public virtual List<Image> Image { get; set; }     

    }

public class Image
    {
        public int ImageID { get; set; }

        // Attributes       

        [Required]
        public int DescriptionID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DescriptionID")]
        public virtual Description Description { get; set; }

        public virtual List<ImageSection> ImageSection { get; set; }
    }



public class ImageSection
    {
        public int ImageSectionID { get; set; }

        // Attributes

        public int? ImageID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ImageID")]
        public virtual Image Image { get; set; }

     }
```

I have `DescriptionID`. What will be the linq to get all the `ImageSection`s having that DescriptionID ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you do not need to join three tables given the description of your problem. As you already have the `DescriptionID` that you want to join on you can ignore the `Description` table.

Try this:

```
var query1 =
    from i in db.Images
    where i.DescriptionID == descriptionID
    join s in db.ImageSections on i.ImageID equals s.ImageID
    select s;
```

However, since your table definitions already contain the child collections you could do a basic `SelectMany` without worrying about joins per se.

Try this as an alternative:

```
var query2 =
    from d in db.Descriptions
    where d.DescriptionID == descriptionID
    from i in d.Image
    from s in i.ImageSection
    select s;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = dbContext.Images.Include(i => i.ImageSections)
                 .Where(j => j.DescriptionID == 1)
                 .SelectMany(im => im.ImageSections).ToList();
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
var descriptions = new List<Description>();

            var descriptionId = 1;

            var result =
                descriptions.Where(d => d.DescriptionID == descriptionId).SelectMany(
                    im => im.Image.SelectMany(ims=> ims.ImageSection));
```